# SwiftUI code too long for the compiler to type-check it, but I can't seem to break it down into parts

Tags: ios, json, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I am trying to make a view iteratively from a JSON file fetched from a PHP URL. The view is made with a for each loop to create an information box for every different station in the JSON and also makes them a navigation link. Ideally, I would tap the box to get more information on a specific tide station (all station data hasn't been presented on the view yet).

Since I am using a for each loop, I represent the current station number in the data array with i. In order to get the same data as the box I click I use the same i number for other relevant data.

My issue is that as I am building everything in the same for each loop to keep that number i in the scope, my code gets too long for the compiler to check. I heard that this could happen even if the code wasn't too long but simply for a typing mistake somewhere, but I have yet to find a mistake that breaks the code and truly believe it is due to the length as it was working if I commented-out some parts.

To resolve that I understand I need to break my code into different sections for the compiler to check them individually so as not to start the process every time.

However, as I am building everything into the for each loop to have the i number in the scope, I cannot make sub-views that use that number.

I am not entirely sure this is the question that would best solve my issue, but **how can I pass the for each loop parameter into another view/function/or something else?**

I apologize for the code being very rough and not following good coding practices, if not just for SwiftUI, I am quite inexperienced with programming in general. I left the entirety of the code to be sure not to leave any possibility out.

```html
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON
import MapKit

public var array_tides_site_name = [String]()
public var array_tides_next_lw_time = [String]()
public var array_tides_next_lw_height = [Double]()
public var array_tides_next_hw_time = [String]()
public var array_tides_next_hw_height = [Double]()
public var array_tides_tidal_state = [String]()
public var array_tides_latitude = [Double]()
public var array_tides_longitude = [Double]()
public var array_tides_observed_height = [Double]()
public var array_tides_predicted_height = [Double]()
public var array_tides_surge = [Double]()

struct Previews_GeneralTides_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GeneralTidesView()
    }
}

struct GeneralTidesView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
            
            ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                
                VStack (alignment: .center) {
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Image(systemName: "chart.xyaxis.line")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                        .frame(width: 300, height: 300, alignment: .center)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Text("More Stations")
                        .font(.title3)
                        .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.primary, .secondary], startPoint: .topLeading, endPoint: .bottomTrailing))
                        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: 40)
                        .background(.thickMaterial)
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    Divider()
                        .onAppear() {loadStationData()}
                    
                    Spacer()
                    
                    StationList()
                    
                }
                .navigationBarTitle("Tides")
                .navigationBarTitleDisplayMode(.inline)
        }
    }
}

func loadStationData(){
    
let generalTideUrl = "http://www.pla.co.uk/hydrographics/ajax/ltoverview.php"

AF.request(generalTideUrl, method: .get).responseJSON(){ (generalTideResponse) in
    switch generalTideResponse.result {
    case .success:
        //print(generaltideresponse.result)
        let generalTideResult = try? JSON(data: generalTideResponse.data!)
        //print(generaltideresult)
        //print(generalTideResult!["tides"])
        let generalTideArray = generalTideResult!["tides"]
        
        array_tides_site_name.removeAll()
        array_tides_next_lw_time.removeAll()
        array_tides_next_lw_height.removeAll()
        array_tides_next_hw_time.removeAll()
        array_tides_next_hw_height.removeAll()
        array_tides_tidal_state.removeAll()
        array_tides_latitude.removeAll()
        array_tides_longitude.removeAll()
        array_tides_observed_height.removeAll()
        array_tides_predicted_height.removeAll()
        array_tides_surge.removeAll()
        
        for i in generalTideArray.arrayValue {
            //print(i)
            
            let site_name = i["site_name"].stringValue
            array_tides_site_name.append(site_name)
            
            var next_lw_time = i["next_lw_time"].stringValue
            let lwRange = next_lw_time.startIndex..<next_lw_time.index(next_lw_time.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
            next_lw_time.removeSubrange(lwRange)
            array_tides_next_lw_time.append(next_lw_time)
            
            let next_lw_height = i["next_lw_height"].doubleValue
            array_tides_next_lw_height.append(next_lw_height)
            
            var next_hw_time = i["next_hw_time"].stringValue
            let hwRange = next_hw_time.startIndex..<next_hw_time.index(next_hw_time.startIndex, offsetBy: 11)
            next_hw_time.removeSubrange(hwRange)
            array_tides_next_hw_time.append(next_hw_time)
            
            let next_hw_height = i["next_hw_height"].doubleValue
            array_tides_next_hw_height.append(next_hw_height)
            
            let tidal_state = i["tidal_state"].stringValue
            array_tides_tidal_state.append(tidal_state)
            
            let latitude = i["latitude"].doubleValue
            array_tides_latitude.append(latitude)
            
            let longitude = i["longitude"].doubleValue
            array_tides_longitude.append(longitude)
            
            let predictedHeight = i["predicted_height"].doubleValue
            array_tides_predicted_height.append(predictedHeight)
            
            let observedHeight = i["observed_height"].doubleValue
            array_tides_observed_height.append(observedHeight)
            
            let surge = i["surge_height"].doubleValue
            array_tides_surge.append(surge)
        }
        
        break
    case .failure:
        print(generalTideResponse.error!)
        break
    }
}.resume()
}


struct StationList: View {
    @State private var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.5, longitude: -0.12), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.6, longitudeDelta: 0.6))

    
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ForEach(0..<array_tides_site_name.count) { i in
            
            NavigationLink(destination: Group{
                
                VStack(alignment: .center) {
                    stationNavLink()
                    Text(array_tides_site_name[i])
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                    
                    Map(coordinateRegion: $mapRegion, annotationItems: [Location(name: array_tides_site_name[i], coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: array_tides_latitude[i], longitude: array_tides_longitude[i]))]) { location in
                        MapMarker(coordinate: location.coordinate)}
                        .frame(width: screenWidth, height: 250)
                    
                    
                    HStack {
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundStyle(.thinMaterial)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 120)
                            .overlay {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading , spacing: 10) {
                                    
                                    Text("Next Low Tide:")
                                    
                                    HStack {Text("Time: "); Text(array_tides_next_lw_time[i])}.foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    
                                    HStack {Text("Height: "); Text(array_tides_next_lw_height[i].description); Text("m")}.foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    
                                     }
                            }
                        
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
                            .foregroundStyle(.thinMaterial)
                            .frame(width: 150, height: 120)
                            .overlay {
                                
                                VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 10) {
                                    
                                    Text("Next High Tide:")
                                    
                                    HStack {Text("Time: "); Text(array_tides_next_hw_time[i])}.foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    
                                    HStack {Text("Height: "); Text(array_tides_next_hw_height[i].description); Text("m")}.foregroundColor(.secondary)
                                    
                                     }
                            }
                        
                        
                    }
                    
                    Text(array_tides_surge[i].description)
                    
                }
                
            }){
            
            ZStack {
                
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                    .strokeBorder(.white.opacity(0.3), lineWidth: 1)
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).fill(.thinMaterial))
                    .frame(width: screenWidth - 40, height: 80)
                    .overlay() {
                        
                        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                                                     
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Text(array_tides_site_name[i])
                                .padding(.leading, 10)
                                .foregroundStyle(LinearGradient(colors: [.secondary, .secondary.opacity(0.8)], startPoint: .leading, endPoint: .trailing))

                            Spacer()
                            
                            Divider()
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Group {
                            HStack(){
                                Spacer()
                                Text("High Water: ")
                                Text(array_tides_next_hw_time[i])
                                Spacer()
                                Text("Low Water: ")
                                Text(array_tides_next_lw_time[i])
                                Spacer()
                                
                                if array_tides_tidal_state[i] == "Flood" { Image(systemName: "arrow.up").foregroundColor(.green) }
                                else { Image(systemName: "arrow.down").foregroundColor(.red) }
                                
                                Spacer()
                                }
                            }
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


var stationNavLink: some View {
    Text(array_tides_surge[currentStation])
}


struct Location: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
}
```

Comment: Simply your code, make smaller views. This is usually caused by a typo or excessive type checking in a view.

Comment: You have one fundamental bad design choice, which has lead to a second poor implementation requirement, which is leading to your compiler problem.  First, don't use separate arrays for the different properties.  Create a `struct` with the required properties and create a single array of these structs.  Make the struct conform to `Identifiable` and you can use `ForEach(myArrayOfStructs) { tideStation in ...}` instead of having to try and use indices.  In the loop you can access the properties of `tideStation` and pass `tideStation` to subviews easily.

Answer (score 0):

Having multiple, associated, arrays to hold your data is a definite [code smell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell). You risk having data get out of sync between the arrays and as you can see, loading and accessing data involves a lot of code.

You can start by creating some [Codable] structs to hold you data.  [quicktype.io](https://app.quicktype.io) can do this for.  Simply paste in your JSON and you get the structs you need.

I have modified `Tide` to conform to `Hashable` and `Identifiable` to make it easier to use in SwiftUI lists.

Also note the use of `CodingKeys` to convert the properties to Swift naming conventions.

```
// MARK: - TideData
struct TideData: Codable {
    let timezone: String
    let tides: [Tide]
}

// MARK: - Tide
struct Tide: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {
    let siteID, siteStation: Int
    let siteName: String
    let latitude, longitude: Double
    let received: String
    let observedHeight, predictedHeight, surgeHeight: Double
    let nextLwTime: String
    let nextLwHeight: Double
    let nextHwTime: String
    let nextHwHeight: Double
    let tidalState: String
    
    var id: Int {
        return siteID
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case siteID = "site_id"
        case siteStation = "site_station"
        case siteName = "site_name"
        case latitude, longitude
        case received = "Received"
        case observedHeight = "observed_height"
        case predictedHeight = "predicted_height"
        case surgeHeight = "surge_height"
        case nextLwTime = "next_lw_time"
        case nextLwHeight = "next_lw_height"
        case nextHwTime = "next_hw_time"
        case nextHwHeight = "next_hw_height"
        case tidalState = "tidal_state"
    }
}
```

Now you can move your loading code into its own class.  Make this an `ObservableObject` and have it publish the tide data.

Since our structs conform to `Codable` we can use AlamoFire's inbuilt JSON decoding and transformation

```
lass Loader:ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var tides: [Tide] = []
    
    func load() {
        let generalTideUrl = "https://www.pla.co.uk/hydrographics/ajax/ltoverview.php"
        
        AF.request(generalTideUrl, method: .get).responseDecodable(of: TideData.self){ (generalTideResponse) in
            switch generalTideResponse.result {
            case .success(let tideData):
                self.tides = tideData.tides
                print(self.tides)
            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Much more succinct!

Finally, we can use this data in a SwiftUI view

I have simplified your views for the sake of this answer, but I am sure you will get the idea.

```
struct GeneralTidesView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var loader: Loader
    
    var body: some View {
        
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(loader.tides) { station in
                    NavigationLink(destination: StationView(station:station)) {
                    Text(station.siteName)
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }.onAppear {
            self.loader.load()
        }
    }
}

struct Previews_GeneralTides_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        GeneralTidesView(loader: Loader())
    }
}

struct StationView: View {
    var station: Tide
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            HStack {
                Text("Predicted Height")
                Text("\(station.observedHeight)")
            }
            HStack {
                Text("Predicted Height")
                Text("\(station.predictedHeight)")
            }
        }.navigationTitle(station.siteName)
    }
}
```

You can see how having a struct with properties makes it much easier to pass data around. Also, since all of the properties are in a single struct, we no longer need to work about array indices.